# C#- Validation for date year less than 1753

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

SQL accepts minimum date year value of 1753.

I have below code which I would expect to validate the year but it does not .

```
args.IsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(args.Value.Trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out test);
```

How do I fix this? I need to check if format is mm/dd/yyyy as well as for valid month,day or year

Comment: Wrong. The minimum value for Date is `0001-01-01`. The minimum value fro DateTime2 is `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. The 1753 limit is only for the outdated `DateTime` data type., and that's not the only reason why it's outdated. I'm on my cell so I can't link it but google "never use datetime again" and you'll see why.

Comment: What is the value of `args.Value.Trim()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you're currently checking is whether the value can be parsed. If you *also* want to check something about the value, you have to do that with a normal condition. Fortunately you can do that pretty easily using `&& (condition)`. So for example:

```
args.IsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(args.Value.Trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out test) &&
    test.Year >= 1753;
```

(That's if you really need to check that the year is at least 1753 of course.  Zohar Peled's comment may well be more useful to you, in terms of suggesting a better field type, or correcting misunderstandings of the type you're using.)

Comment: (Apologies for originally having the condition the wrong way round. Fixed now!)